# Preferred method to get another bean: evaluating EL or @Inject

Tags: jsf, cdi, el

We can get jsf bean by two ways:

```
JobApplicant jobApplicant = (JobApplicant) FacesUtils.getManagedBean("jobApplicant");
```

or

Ingecting the property

```
@Inject
JobApplicant jobApplicant //getter and setter required
```

In first way we can get a bean right in method, so in does not allocate memory. If it be class member (with Inject) it allways requred some memory to hold a reference to that bean. Also in this case the scope of `jobApplicant` must be at least not shorter than a scope of outer bean which inject the `jobApplicant`. But in case of using utils the scope could be a `view` for example which is shorter than `session` scope of outer bean, yea?

What is the best method to get a bean?

Comment: `@Inject` is not JSF, it's CDI - different technology and getter and setter are not required.

Comment: There isn't really a "best method"; it depends on whatever constraints your environment places on you. Forget all that memory talk, that's just premature optimization-speak (unless you've actually benchmarked and there are real performance problems). As far as versatility and extensibility goes, maybe `@Inject` is preferable

Answer (score 0):

One of the key benefits of dependency injection is the inversion of control pattern. Instead of creating instances yourself, you tell the manageing container which dependencies you need.
So you should stick to the "@Inject" approach whenever possible. You can use it with fields, constructors and setters, so your statement that it requires getters/setters is not true.

You will notice that testing gets a lot easier when your code does not call any static factory methods but just requires injecting a bean.

Comment: I don't think `getManagedBean()` "creates instance yourself" (as in `new Bean()`), but that it just programmatically gets a managed bean reference from JSF/CDI context. So your answer is most likely off.

Comment: Well, I might have not been clear here ... from th IoC point of view, it doesn't matter if you call "new" yourself or "getManagedBean".  What matters is that you are creating a new instance (or access a new reference) from within the executed code which makes the dependency a) intransparent and b) hard to test/simulate.